# Как называются такие схемы и на чем их рисуют?

Tags: ui, ux

Вот такие схемы с крестиками:

[image: http://wnfx.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/bank.jpg?711351]
http://www.foreui.com/store/items/Web_Store/preview/

Comment: Вы сами дали ссылку http://www.foreui.com/

Comment: То есть такие схемы официально называются foreui?

Comment: Перенесите картинки на сайт, пожалуйста

Comment: конкретно блок "с крестиками" это обозначается место под изображение(image).  [ссылка на онлайн сервис](http://wireframe.cc/) по созданию таких макетов

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос-картинку невозможно найти в поисковиках, а следовательно, он бесполезен для будущих посетителей сайта.

Comment: @kff а как это текстом оформить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такие наброски интерфейса обычно называют англицизмом "мокапы" или более русскими словами - макеты (дизайн-макеты), прототипы.

Есть множество онлайн инструментов для прототипирования интерфейса. Я пользуюсь [ninjamock.com](http://ninjamock.com)